# Javascript closures cause memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I read this of the book "Professional Javascript for Web Developers"
but I cannot comprehend the explanation provided in the book.

```
let outer = function() {
    let name = 'Jake';
    return function() {
     return name;
    };
   };
```

> This leaks the memory allocated for name. This code creates an
> internal closure, so as long as the outer function exists, the name
> variable cannot be cleaned up because there will be a persistent
> reference to it through that closure. If the contents of the name
> variable were extremely large instead of just a short string, major
> problems could result.

I'm don't know if this variable will be passed by a copy or a reference, but from my understanding:

- Why would the name variable not freed, if it passes a copy to the return headless function?
- Why would it be a memory leak if it passes a reference and is being used?

(I'm new to JS, my question might seem silly but it really confuses me and please help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variables declared inside a function will be freed when the function returns, **expect** those which are used inside a closure. In your example, the variable `name` has to be in the memory, until the returned function is called.